# Нужно написать UI тест на Python для https://www.metric-conversions.org/ Тест на преобразование температуры по Цельсию в температуру по Фаренгейту

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, ui, pytest

Установил selenium. Дальше вот этого дело не двинулось. как посмотреть приходит ли что то вообще по запросу? как узнать структуру JSON если он приходит. Это первая попытка UI тестирования. не корите строго.

```
import requests as requests

def test_get_locations_for_us_90210_check_status_code_equals_200():
    response = requests.get("https://api.metric-conversions.org/length/meters-to-feet.htm")
```

Comment: Сначала просто без pytest как скрипт запустите и выведите что приходит в `response.text`, или через postman например посмотрите ответ сервера, потом уже исходя из этого пишите тест.

Comment: @insolor это мысль. спасибо!